# default python won't switch to homebew installation

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I know this question has been asked - but none of the solutions there seem to be working. I recently found out that on Mac OS, the native installation of python isn't very good. So, I installed homebrew, and installed Python 2 through there. My path is as follows:

```
~ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

However, I still get the following:

```
~ which python
/usr/bin/python

~ which python2
/usr/local/bin/python2
```

It's also probably important to note that my `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile` and `~/.zshrc` files are empty.

Somehow, I think I got pip to work with the `python2` (homebrew) installation. Basically, I did `pip install pandas` and I get the following outputs for the two python interpreters:

```
~ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

That is, it doesn't appear with the default python installation. However, I also have the following:

```
~ python2
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 25 2017, 09:53:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>>
```

So, pandas is imported in the python2 (homebrew) python, but not the standard one. How can I get it so that the default python is my homebrew python? I also read somewhere that `brew link python` would work, but when I do that I get

```
~ brew link python
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14
To relink: brew unlink python && brew link python
```

I want to be able to just use `python my_file.py` and have it use the homebrew installation. (Not sure if it's related, but hopefully this would also allow Sublime to use the homebrew install when I hit command + B).

Sorry for the long post, new computer and I'm trying to get this all correct before I do any big projects and find out halfway through that things aren't working the way I need them to.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `brew doctor` have anything interesting to say?

Comment: All it says is `Your system is ready to brew.`

Answer (score 1):

The macOS system Python is installed at `/usr/bin/python`. This is the only one called `python` on your path.

Homebrew doesn't create a link for `python` in `/usr/local/bin`. If you want one you can create it yourself:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Alternatively, just update your shebang lines to specify `python2` or `python3`, which is probably better anyway (explicit is better than implicit).